# Can I use jQuery to check if the entire page contains text?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to use jQuery to tell if an entire webpage includes some text? For instance, on StackOverflow, I can return any divs that contain the word "Badges" by using the following in the console:

```
$("div:contains('Badges')")
```

However, when I write:

```
$(document:contains('Badges'))
```

or

```
$("document:contains('Badges')")
```

I get an error. How can I check if any element on the page contains certain text and return those elements?

Comment: You understand that if an element contains the text you want, all ancestors of it will also match and so be returned as well?

Comment: Do you need to get each individual item contains the string?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I'm looking to return just the elements that contain the text directly.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("html:contains('Badges')")
```

You could also use:

```
$("body:contains('Badges')")
```

Comment: This returns the entire `html` or `body` of the DOM. I was hoping to just return the elements that directly contain the text in a list.

Answer (score 1):

`$("*").filter(function() { return $(this).text() ==="Badges";});`

This one will check the contents of inner children also.

Edit :  changed to return only elements with exact content as "Badges".

Comment: Hm, it's close but this returns everything, even if it's just one of its children that contains the text. I wanted to return just the elements that directly contain that text.

Comment: Ok.  Fixed the code.  I tested this. https://jsfiddle.net/3tr5oyp2/1/ It should accommodate your requirements.  Remember the 'filter' function.  Everyone neglects it until last moment :)

Comment: Oh and change the `===` to starts with our ends with our as per your needs. The above code needs exact value and will reject even if it has exact value +inner elements coz it will consider those as part of the text and hence fail

Answer (score 1):

To only select the deepest nodes that contains the text, use something like this

```
var textToFind = 'Badges';

$(function(){
  var allTextNodes = $("*").contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
  });
  
  var matchingNodes = allTextNodes.filter(function(){return this.textContent.indexOf(textToFind) > -1;}).parent();

  // matchingNodes is a list of all nodes (tags) that contain the searched text
});
```

---

or in plugin form

```
$(function(){
  $.fn.nodesWithText = function(textToFind){
    var allTextNodes = $("*", this)
                        .addBack()
                        .contents()
                        .filter(function () {
                          return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
                        }),
        matchingNodes = allTextNodes
                          .filter(function(){
                            return this
                              .textContent
                              .indexOf(textToFind) > -1;
                          });
    return matchingNodes.parent();
  };
});
```

and you can use it as `$(document).nodesWithText('Badges');` which will search the whole document for any elements with the specified text or `$('div').nodesWithText('Badges');` which will search inside `div` elements for any other node that contains the specified text. (*the second use method will not return `div` elements, but will search inside `div` elements for any kind of tag that contains the text*)

**Demo at** http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/XmmOmb

(*the plugin could be simplified to do the text matching at the same time it checks for node types. I made it in two passes to see the actual steps needed more clearly*)

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).text().includes('Badges');`

This will answer this question's title "Can I use jQuery to check if the entire page contains text?"

It won't return the nodes though.